# PHP: input type button/submit not working to view the result when using an image

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, button

I have a button where it will display the playlist of a building...

**Scenario 1:**
I tried the two types of button, the other one is image and the other one is button...

When I tried the to used the image type.

Here's the code:

```
echo "<input type='image'  src='image/view.png' name='viewResult[]' value='" . $row['fldBldgName']."' onClick=\"this.form.action='looptime_utilization_process_viewer.php'; this.form.submit()\"> ";
```

Its not displaying the correct output.. instead its display a number and I dont know where the program get it...I checked my database and there is no output like that...

**Scenario 2:**
I tried the type button/submit and its display the correct output...

Here's the code:

```
echo "<input type='submit'  name='viewResult[]' value='" . $row['fldBldgName']."' onClick=\"this.form.action='looptime_utilization_process_viewer.php'; this.form.submit()\"> ";
```

[Here's the sample output I want:](http://postimg.org/image/wbiigechn/)

The result of that output is the scenario one....I also tried the background image in button but I don't like that.